# How can a springboot application deployed on PCF read messages from Websphere MQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, cloud-foundry

I'm developing a spring boot application that will be deployed in pivotal cloud foundry and it needs to read/listen to messages from Websphere MQ. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where is the MQ queue manager? Do you have an IP address and port for it? Do you have connectivity to that IP address?

Comment: I have the following details related to MQ - hostname, port, channel, QueueManagerName @MoragHughson

Comment: Then yes, you should be able to get messages from an IBM MQ queue.

Comment: What errors are you seeing that are stopping you from doing so?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I want to know how to do it. what are the different possible solutions. @MoragHughson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! Follow this tutorial to get up and running - https://developer.ibm.com/languages/spring/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/

Change the hard-coded queue to pick up the queue name from `application.properties` eg.

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}")
    public void receive(MyDataObject data) {
       ...
    }
```

where `application.properties` would amongst all the other required settings, something like:

```
queue.name=DEV.QUEUE.2
```

See https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring for a list of the properties that you can set. The rest is just spring JMS. For example, if you want Spring to perform object marshelling / unmarshelling make sure to add a `MessageConverter` which is usually a  `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`

There are guides to help you get your spring app deployed to cloud foundry:

From the CF perspective - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/getting-started-deploying-apps/gsg-spring.html

and from the Spring perspective - https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts-cloud-foundry-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

> I'm developing a spring boot application that will be deployed in pivotal cloud foundry and it needs to read/listen to messages from Websphere MQ. Is there a way to do that?

Yes, it should be possible. What you need to first validate is that you have network connectivity (DNS resolves, traffic is routable and no firewalls block access) from traffic on your CF foundation to your IBM MQ.

If any of those do not work, you need to talk with your network or possibly MQ administrators to get traffic allowed.

You can validate by running `cf ssh` to enter a container on your CF foundation and then using `nc -v <IP> <port>` which will attempt to make a TCP connection to your MQ IP/port. If you see netcat indicate that a connection was established, then you're all set.

Beyond that, you would just develop the Spring Boot application like you would if you were deploying a Spring Boot application anywhere else (i.e. there nothing specific you must do). You could put your creds into `application.properties` or use env variables to pass in the credentials to your app.

If you want to get a little fancier, you can look at [java-cfenv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv) which can be used to perform dynamic service binding, but you don't have to.

With service binding, you could create a user-provided service (`cf cups`) and use that to store your IBM MQ connection info/creds. Then you `cf bind` the service to your app, and you app will have access to the bound credentials by reading the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable, which `java-cfenv` will do automatically for you.

The benefit of using service binding instead of putting your credentials into `application.properties` or env variables is that you can `cf unbind` / `cf bind` and move services around very easily. All you need to do is restart your app, and it'll start using the new service.